# OAuthProvider for Twitter iOS Log In with Firebase has wrong constructor

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication, twitter

I am using the following tutorial to implement Twitter log in for an iOS app: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/twitter-login.

I follow all the steps & when I get to `var provider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "twitter.com")`, Xcode is not happy. I get *Argument passed to call that takes no arguments*.

I am importing Firebase and installing the Pods as shown.

Any idea on what could be going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had already face the same problem, and it was solved by updating Firebase/Auth by Pod

```
pod update
```

Comment: For some reason pod update, removing Firebase/Auth, and reinstalling it doesn't work for me. Also, I made sure I cleaned the build folder every time.